# WindowsPhone - Send/receive data by USB

Tags: cordova, mobile, xamarin, windows-phone, smartphone

I need to do a mobile application that send/receive data to a custom device by USB and I can't find how to do that in Windows Phone.

Edit: I think I must clarify a point after seeing answers: I don't want to send or receive files. I need to send custom commands like on RS232. The commands are on text form and should allow my app to read/write device's attributes.

In preference, I would like to do the application multiplatform with a tool like Xamarin, Cordova or other. But if it is not possible, I will make an application for each platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google: usb on-the-go windows phone

Answer (score 0):

USB transfer of data is not available for the windows phone like it was for the pocket pc (windows ce).   You should use a service like onedrive, drop box, box, google drive, etc to transfer files between desktop and phone